# Where to download MySQL server 5.0.77-log

Tags: linux, mysql, redhat, rpm, mysql5

I have MySQL Server version: 5.0.77-log Source distribution on a RHEL6 server.

I need to reinstall it on a second RHEL6 server to set up a testing environment but I cannot find where to download this exact version.

Thanks!

Comment: Someone _downgraded_ MySQL when setting up the _first_ server? If they're still at the company, go have a long chat with them. You'll probably have to contact your Oracle rep to get this...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the download at http://downloads.mysql.com/archives/community/.

However, to install it on RHEL6 requires downgrading many other core components. It's recommended to instead set up a RHEL5 server and install it there, if need be.